# R: Change the Size of Nodes in Graph

Tags: r

I am working with the R programming language.

I found this R code that produces a network graph where the nodes have different sizes:

```
library(visNetwork)
library(igraph)

 my_data <- data.frame( "Col_C" = c("AAA", "AAA", "AAB", "AAB", "AAB", "ABC", "CDE", "CDE", "CDE", "AAB", "AAB", "AAE"), "Col_D" = c("AAB", "AAC", "AAC", "ABC", "CDE", "CDE", "AAB", "AAE", "ADF", "AAE", "ADF","ADF") )

 final <- data.frame(col = unique(unlist(my_data)))

 final$size = c(6,10,1,20,50,1,5) 

 graph_B <- graph_from_data_frame(my_data, directed = FALSE, vertices = final)

 visIgraph(graph_B)
```

[image]

**My Question:** I am trying to apply this logic here to change the sizes of nodes in the following network graph:

```
library(tidyverse)
library(visNetwork)
library(htmlwidgets)

set.seed(123)
mat <- matrix(runif(5*5), nrow = 5, ncol = 5)
mat <- round(mat, 2)

nodes <- data.frame(id = 1:5)
edges <- data.frame(from = sample(1:5, 100, replace = TRUE), to = sample(1:5, 100, replace = TRUE))

nodes$shape <- 'circle'
nodes$size <- sample(1:10, 5, replace = TRUE) # assign random sizes to nodes
edges$weight <- apply(edges, 1, function(x) mat[x["from"], x["to"]])
edges$label <- as.character(apply(edges, 1, function(x) mat[x["from"], x["to"]]))

nodes$label <- paste("Node", 1:5)

    nodes$size <- sample(1:10, 5, replace = TRUE)
    nodes$value <- nodes$size


network <- visNetwork(nodes, edges) %>%
    visEdges(arrows = list(to = list(enabled = TRUE))) %>%
    visIgraphLayout(layout = "layout_in_circle")

network
```

**However, when I run the above code - the size of the nodes have not changed:**

[image]

Can someone please tell me what I am doing wrong and what I can do to fix this?

Thanks!

Comment: thats because of how vis.js is set up, shape = "circle" donesnt work well with nodesize. on the top its shape "dot" wich places the label outside, than size will be applied.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Its not very clear, for some reason the `size` parameter only works with certain shapes, that have labels outside the nodes (for example `dot` which is applied to your top image). To control size of shapes such as `circle`you have to change the label size using a scaling argument applied to value. See the comments in the example code below:

```
set.seed(123)
mat <- matrix(runif(5*5), nrow = 5, ncol = 5)
mat <- round(mat, 2)

nodes <- data.frame(id = 1:5)
edges <- data.frame(from = sample(1:5, 100, replace = TRUE), to = sample(1:5, 100, replace = TRUE))

nodes$label <- paste("Node", 1:5)
nodes$shape <- 'circle'
nodes$value <- 1:5 # assign label size value same as label

edges$weight <- apply(edges, 1, function(x) mat[x["from"], x["to"]])
edges$label <- as.character(apply(edges, 1, function(x) mat[x["from"], x["to"]]))


visNetwork(nodes, edges) %>%
  # use scaling to scale by label
  visNodes(shape = "circle", scaling = list(label = list(min = 10, max = 20))) %>% 
  visEdges(arrows = list(to = list(enabled = TRUE))) %>%
  visIgraphLayout(layout = "layout_in_circle")
```

[image]